# Minimising two maximum edges in s-t path

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, greedy-algorithms

I've been trying to solve the following [problem](http://www.e-olimp.com.ua/en/problems/1727):

Problem is the following: 
Given a graph and  a pair of nodes $s$, $t$   you have to find the path from $s$ to $t$ which  minimises the sum of its two largest edges.

Here's what i've come up with:
I am executing the Prim algorithm  with a slight modification. The cost of a node $u$ (i.e what's saved in the heap) is the following:
Minimum sum of two largest edges that can lead from $s$ to $u$, where said edges are either on the tree constructed thus far (via Prim)  or one of them can be an edge $e=(a,u)$ where $a$ is a node on the tree.

The reasoning of why this should work – I think – is similar to the Prim's algorithm proof.  The problem reminds me of the Minimum Bottleneck Tree which can also be solved by MST.

However, the algorithm fails on three test cases. I've checked the source code for errors but I didn't find anything. This means that the error is likely in my algorithm. (Of course, I can  post the code if needed.)

Can anyone  either show a testcase where the algorithm fails or give a hint in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. You say you already have three test cases where the algorithm fails. Why do you want more? If you do post the algorithm, please use pseudocode, rather than just dumping the source.

Comment: i don't know the tests. Just the fact that my algorithm fails those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumption on how you handle paths of length 1 is correct (the weight of the path is the weight of the single edge), your example should fail on the graph described by the following adjacency matrix:

$$\begin{matrix}
&s&u&v&t\\
s&-&3&4&-\\
u&3&-&3&-\\
v&4&3&-&3\\
t&-&-&3&-
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: You're right. I get 7 instead of 6. Thank you!